# CSS: Convert a two column stack into a single with @media queries

Tags: css, wordpress, html, media-queries

I have two `<divs>` (left-col, right-col) containing Wordpress posts (the more recent, the lower the number)

```
left-col | right-col
--------------------
--post 1 | --post 2
--post 3 | --post 4
--post 5 | --post 6
```

Using `@media` and `CSS` I would like to convert this into a single column like this:

```
single-col
----------
--post 1
--post 2
--post 3
--post 4
etc.
```

Notice that I am not trying to push the `right-col` under the `left-col` but also change how the posts pile up.

Currently my s have following relevant values:

```
#left-col {
    width: 420px;
    float: left;
}
#right-col {
    width: 420px;
    float: left;    
}
```

**ALTERNATIVE QUESTION**: is there any other way to get this two column layout flat for mobile screens, even if it needs more thank CSS/media query?

Comment: assuming your `left-col` is a `<div>` and `right-col` is a separate `<div>` you aren't going to be able to interleave the posts like you want without changing your markup, i.e. cant be done with CSS alone..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `jQuery`, it comes with some functions to manipulate the content of `divs`, like `append()`, `replaceWith()`, `insertAfter()`.

You could move elements from one `div` to another, flush or append `divs`.

See the explanations to those function here:

[append()](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/default.asp),

[replaceWith()](http://api.jquery.com/replacewith/)

[insertAfter()](http://api.jquery.com/insertafter/)

You might wanna check [W3Schools jQuery tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/default.asp) first, if you are unfamiliar with jQuery.

Answer (score 1):

I'd solve this without the column divs and possibly use the [nth-child css selector](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_nth-child.asp)

Something like:

Demo on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/r6mKB/2/)

```
.posts > div {
    width: 100%;
}

@media all and (min-width: 600px){
    .posts > div {
         width: 50%;
    }

    // optional: additional styles specific to either column
    .posts > div:nth-child(2n) {
         color: red;
    }

    .posts > div:nth-child(2n+1) {
         color: blue;
    }
}

<div class="posts">
    <div>Post Content</div>
    <div>Post Content</div>
    <div>Post Content</div>
    <div>Post Content</div>
    <div>Post Content</div>
    <div>Post Content</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Wow, thank you. I have setup a jfiddle with your code and add included in your post. It is better than any solution I have tried so far!

Comment: Unfortunately, it produces a grid layout that has turned out not to fit my needs, since the post contents won't necessary have the same height.I still have to find a way to get my two col solution work, thanks again anyway!